# How to autimatically include URL in JIRA issue collector?

Tags: javascript, html, jira-plugin

In the JIRA issue collector, there is an optional checkbox to include data such as URL.

**"Include data about your current environment, like the browser and page URL. This helps us understand your feedback better."**

I want the checkbox to be selected automatically when the plugin is loaded. I tried the following and it's half-working. The checkbox is selected automatically, but the created issue does not include the URL. Not sure what's going on?

This is what I  have:

JavaScript

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "https://sol-jira.atlassian.net/s/d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e-T/o2joag/b/24/e73395c53c3b10fde2303f4bf74ffbf6/_/download/batch/com.atlassian.jira.collector.plugin.jira-issue-collector-plugin:issuecollector-embededjs/com.atlassian.jira.collector.plugin.jira-issue-collector-plugin:issuecollector-embededjs.js?locale=en-US&collectorId=<id>",
    type: "get",
    cache: true,
    dataType: "script"
});
window.ATL_JQ_PAGE_PROPS = {
    '<id>': {
        "triggerFunction": function(showCollectorDialog) {
            //Requires that jQuery is available!
            $("#docsFeedbackTrigger").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                showCollectorDialog();
            });
        },
        fieldValues: {
            recordWebInfo: '1', // field Name
            recordWebInfoConsent: ['1'] // field Id
        }
    }
};
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="docsFeedbackTrigger" class="docs-issue-collector">Provide feedback</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The above code is correct, but you will also need to add the environment field in the project settings. The Environment field option will be visible in the Issue collector settings.

[Environment Field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUvgT.png)

That's it. You don't even need to select it. The URL data will be visible in the created issue.

[URL in the JIRA Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rARj.png)